# How to sumproduct with multiple search and dictionary

Tags: excel, dictionary, search, dynamic, sumproduct

I want to calculate the `sumproduct` as pictured in the table in the "Revenue" column. However, the dataset is fairly big, I'm limited to excel and the standard functions.

It should find all variables with the keyword "weightl" and "sell" in it and multiply and sum them accordingly per row. In Row 3 for example:

```
2*3+3*6+2*3 = 30
```

I thought of using a kind of a dictionary to alter the search terms and go through each column. But I have no clue on how to put it all together.

I used this

```
{=+isnumber(search("weightl";F2:N2))+isnumber(search("sell";F2:N2))}
```

to create the 1/0 table of the original one in the hope this could lead me somewhere
and

```
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("weight";G2:M2);0)>0;IF(G3:M8<>8888;G3:M8)))
```

to calculate the total sum of the weight values but this doesn't help much here

Can this even be realized with normal functions? if not, how could a solution in VBA look like?

[image: Example Data/structure]

Comment: Are these columns fixed? Sell always seem to come two columns after weight in this data

Comment: Why does column 7 --> 11

Comment: Sorry this was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formula that should do the matching in the way that you're thinking:

```
=SUM(A2:I2*ISNUMBER(FIND("weight",A1:I1))*IFERROR(INDEX(A2:I2,N(IF({1},MATCH("*sell"&RIGHT(A1:I1,LEN(A1:I1)-FIND("weightl",A1:I1)-6),A1:I1,0)))),0))
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

**Note** I'm finding the 'sell' header which matches the 'weightl' header, so weightl1_1_4 will match with sell1_1_4 etc., but I'm now wondering if this is necessary - maybe the weight just matches with the next sell, which would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your "weight" and "sell" columns are always two columns apart, then you can use this **array** formula which looks for the "weight" column and then multiplies it by the column 2 cells to the right:

*`hdrs` refers to the range `$A$1:$I$1` which contains the headers.  But it could refer to the entire row, or a much large portion of Row 1*

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH("*weight*",hdrs)*A2:G2,0) * IFERROR(SEARCH("*weight*",hdrs)*C2:I2,0))
```

If there might be a variable number of columns between "weight" and "sell", then you can try this **array** formula which looks for the "weight" and "sell" columns separately:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A2:I2,1,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("*weight*",hdrs)*COLUMN(hdrs),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(hdrs,"*weight*")))))))*INDEX(A2:I2,1,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH("*sell*",hdrs)*COLUMN(hdrs),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(hdrs,"*weight*"))))))))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

**Note** I just noticed you want to match "weight**1**", so just make the obvious change in the above formulas.